# remote desktop doesn't go to full resolution

Tags: windows-10, remote-desktop, resolution

I often connect to my work computer from home via remote desktop over a vpn.  I have set the display settings in the connection to 1920 x 1080 (the max resolution of my laptop screen) but the window that opens up, though full screen, is a lower resolution.  I used to connect from this same laptop  at a lower resolution but upgraded the screen.  I have edited the connection in notepad and the height and width are specified there as 1080 and 1920 respectively.  I've also tried adjusting it on the connection settings before connecting and have tried setting as full screen but still always get the lower resolution.
I am running Windows 10 Pro on both my laptop and work computer.

Comment: I connected to a different computer at work via remote desktop and it went full screen 1920x1080.  But every time I connect to my computer it gets a lower resolution but still full screen.  The resolution I get is 1536x864.  Does this have something to do with how my laptop used to connect to this computer with a lower resolution and it remembers that somehow?

Comment: Just found out that the resolution issue is specific to my account on this computer only.  If I connect to another computer with any account, including mine, then I get full screen at 1920x1080.  If I connect to my work computer with another account then I get full screen at 1920x1080.  If I connect with my account then I get 1536x864.  So it appears to be remembering when I connected previously with a different resolution.  What do I need to wipe out on my profile on my computer to fix this/reset it?

Answer (score 0):

When connected, left click at the top-left of your Remote connection, then choose smart sizing, then the connection would try to fix the Remote connection Window. And if you would like to make it full screen, maximize it.

For the icons within the remote desktop, you might need to configure the resolution within the connection.

[image]

Comment: Smart sizing only makes it so when it is windowed it shows the whole desktop so there are no scroll bars.  Still getting a low resolution.

Answer (score 0):

Inside of the RDP session right click on the desktop and choose "Screen Resolution".  Click Identify and close out.  It'll tell you the you have to restart to change settings - don't restart!  Just log off the RDP session and log back in, your remote desktop should fill the screen now.

Comment: Please do not post the same answer to multiple questions. If the same information really answers both questions, then one question (usually the newer one) should be closed as a duplicate of the other. You can indicate this by [voting to close it as a duplicate](https://superuser.com/help/privileges/close-questions) or, if you don't have enough reputation for that, [raise a flag](https://superuser.com/help/privileges/flag-posts) to indicate that it's a duplicate. Otherwise tailor your answer to this question and don't just paste the same answer in multiple places.